# Makefile split variable in target execution

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile to handle the compilation of different latex files:

```makefile
SUBJECTS = ${wildcard *.tex}

PDFS = ${SUBJECTS:.tex=.pdf}

ifndef LATEX

LATEX = pdflatex

endif

${PDFS}: ${SUBJECTS}
    ${LATEX} -halt-on-error --shell-escape ${SUBJECTS}
    ${LATEX} -halt-on-error --shell-escape ${SUBJECTS}# Two times to manage LastPage references

all: ${PDFS} chrome-open

build: ${PDFS}
```

It worked fine for now as I only had one latex file in the folder it is used. Although this does not work anymore now I have 2 different latex files as the latex compiler does not accept 2 different latex file to compile in the same command.

As I understand the make behavior, if the ${PDFS} variable contains 2 files, then 2 rules are created, each one with the same dependencies (the full ${SUBJECT} variable.

This leads to un-necessary dependencies for each of the output pdfs and also prevents the files to be compiled as pdflatex does not accept 2 different inputs...

Any idea of a way to create the rules to compile the right file only when it has been modified ?

Comment: Replace `${PDFS}: ${SUBJECTS}` by `%.pdf: %.tex` and `${SUBJECTS}` by `$<` ?

Comment: This is what pattern rules were created for: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html